# Why does server GC block when my object graphs are nicely partitioned in AppDomains?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection, appdomain

I'm trying to profile my server application in a simple (single threaded) loop.

Each cycle of the loop uses a separate AppDomain
Within this AppDomain, a large (200MB?) and horribly interlinked object graph is created. 
Some operation is performed, and the cycle is complete. The objects are retained (because they will theoretically be reused, just not in my test)
The cycle is repeated say 500 times.

I'm seeing a lot of frothiness at the beginning of the loop, as the GC presumably becomes accustomed to what I'm doing. Then all is well, until I hit a GC spikes. The spikes are huge, after which performance is great for 50-100 cycles until the next spike.

I understand (from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20228248/738851)) that the complexity of my object graph within an AppDomain means it is expensive to collect/move. However, there are no links between AppDomains, and only a single link from each AppDomain back to a proxy object in the main AppDomain. So wouldn't the objects in a given AppDomain need moving at most twice, after which time they're in Gen2 and should never need to be moved again, or even looked at, ideally.

I guess we should consider process separation rather than AppDomain separation, because then we have separate heaps. But we are trying to avoid that for now.

What can I do to improve the performance of the GC in this scenario? NB. The current "total"/average GC cost is fine, but I'd like to spread it a little more evenly across cycles.

**Edit**

I've experimented with .Net 4.5.1 in a naive way: I set the `GCSettings.LatencyMode` to each of the 3 available modes, and run the same test. In this scenario, `Interactive` and `SustainedLowLatency` both have worse Gen2 collection freezes than using the `Batch` mode available in 4.0. Possibly less frequent, but worse when they happen.

I will also experiment with changing the latency mode dynamically during the test, possibly forcing GCs early, etc. But it's very much trial and error at the moment. Also, both changing the latency mode and forcing GCs is easier when you're only considering one thread. Even if it works for the test, it may not be applicable to the server

Comment: Doesn't sound more than you seeing gen#2 collections being done. Which of course does look at gen#2 object references. And are expensive. And stops the world on a server prior to .NET 4.5. Tinker with the <gcserver> config element to get background collection, update the .NET version so you can tinker with low-latency mode. And avoid looking at Perfmon graphs that just tell you that you have a lot of objects but doesn't tell you how that actually affects your program behavior.